# adding editText for user input to a url rest call in Android

Tags: android, json, user-interface, parsing

I am using this code to which parses a REST call with JSON as the result.
I want to add an editTestInput with a submit button that is part of the url that is being parsed (basically to make it so a user can search for what they want).

Here is my code that just parses a static url (note: in the url there is a search term variable; this is what I want to make into a user input that will kick off the parsing of the url and return results in JSON format):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView lv;
    public String term = "rabi";
    public String url;
    public EditText editTextInput;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextInput);

        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetSearchItems().execute();
    }

    private class GetSearchItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SearchResults are downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx=" + term + "&gsc.sort=";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray items = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");

                    // looping through All results
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = c.getString("title");
                        String link = c.getString("link");
                        String displayLink = c.getString("displayLink");
                        String formattedUrl = c.getString("formattedUrl");
                        String snippet = c.getString("snippet");

                        // tmp hash map for single result
                        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        item.put("title", title);
                        item.put("link", link);
                        item.put("displayLink", displayLink);
                        item.put("formattedUrl", formattedUrl);
                        item.put("snippet", snippet);

                        // adding contact to result list
                        itemList.add(item);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "title","link", "displayLink", "formattedUrl", "snippet"},
                    new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.link, R.id.displayLink, R.id.formattedUrl, R.id.snippet});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please show me how to alter my current code to accomplish that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding the editTextInput to the onCreate method.
Then I put the code to make the http request into the onClick method.
My application is now working as intended.